# How to determine whether a file is hidden when it has multiple attributes

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm processing all excel files in a particular folder

```
Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(spreadsheetFolder)
excelFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.xlsx")
```

In this folder the "~$weird.xlsx" files sometimes appear, I'm not interested in these files and want to skip them.

I'd like to just skip any file that is hidden. The problem here is that fileinfo.attributes doesn't just contain the hidden attribute, it is

```
Hidden Or Archive Or NotContentIndexed {8226}
```

The code that I've found all over the net only works if hidden is the only attribute, what do I do if there are others too?

I know that I could just ignore anything that starts "~$" but that isn't fun and this problem is bugging me now!

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HasFlag` property. Sample code:

```
Dim excelFiles() As FileInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.xlsx")

For Each curFile In excelFiles
    If (curFile.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)) Then
      'This one is hidden
    End If
Next
```